# Laravel upgrade 5.5

Tags: laravel, composer-php, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade to laravel 5.5 from 5.4. When i run composer update i get:

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.47
    ...
    Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-cors 2.0.* -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-cors[v2.0.0].
    barryvdh/laravel-cors v2.0.0 requires illuminate/contracts ^5.6|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by 
    illuminate/contracts[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19
  ...
  ...
    don't install illuminate/contracts 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/contracts 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/contracts 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
```

My composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.1.",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "dingo/api": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors" : "2.0.*",
...
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
```

What am i missing here? What is wrong?

Comment: I think `barryvdh/laravel-cors` requires min `illuminate/contracts` and `illuminate/support` version 5.6 and with version 5.5 of Laravel they are also version 5.5.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so how should i adjust it?

Comment: I can suggest to upgrade the app to version 6 if the situation allows it or at least 5.8, because 5.5 was released almost 3 years ago and if you continue development of the project in the future more and more packages might require a newer version. Security and more features of the newer versions comes with a priority of course.

Comment: That's my goal. But now i'm in version 5.4. I don't think i should jump to 5.6 directly

Comment: Why not stick to versions that work? v1 of `barryvdh/laravel-cors` will work with Laravel 5.5

Comment: Well not really, barryvdh/laravel-cors doesn't work with 5.5 yet

Comment: What do you mean by that? 'barryvdh/laravel-cors` has been published in late 2013. Why not try to use `^1.0` of that package? Have you even checked the version list on https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors?

Comment: With Laravel 5.5 it is very hard to install it with so many errors. I already tried to install 1.0 but it just kept showing different errors with no fix online. Google it

Comment: when did you install `"barryvdh/laravel-cors"` ? before upgrading to laravel 5.5? or you add this package at the same time you changed  `"laravel/framework"` to version `5.5.*` ?

Comment: i tried both. it was already installed but when upgrading to laravel 5.5 it gave compatibility error. so i deleted it, upgraded laravel and installed it. But it kept showing Class cors does not exist.

Comment: Found a blog regarding a simmilar upgrade. Might be worth taking a look! https://arobs.com/blog/my-experience-upgrading-laravel-framework-5-8-to-8-x/